# POST method not working

Tags: java, android, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am developing an android app which accesses my Oracle database in the cloud through RESTful services , Oracle APEX provided the interface for  creating REST services , On the client side i am able to invoke a GET request through JAVA HttpClient API and the response is Just fine in JSON format.. the problem is when a invoke a POST request i am not getting the appropriate response.i did everything as instructed by the documentation,
(also defined the outbound parameters)
Please have a look at this pic ad tell if i am doing anything wrong
http://i58.tinypic.com/2gt5bb5.png

The code on the client side is like this:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("MNUM", "234564");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());
post.setEntity(se);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity); // this function converts response to string
```

the PL/SQL in the source is:

```
DECLARE
id USER_INFO.m_number%type; //user_info is a table and m_number is its primary key (which i am trying to post from my app)
BEGIN
INSERT into USER_INFO(m_number)
values(:MNUM)
returning m_number into id;
:status := 201;
:location := id;
commit;
END;
```

can anybody tell me why i am unable to POST after all this , any help will be much appreciated , i am stuck at this part from days.
The Error i receive is Service not available.

Comment: Did you check whether you're RESTful service supports POST requests?

Comment: yes, please have a look at the link , that is the interface to creating a POST restful service

Comment: Required secure access - Yes, maybe this make some difference

Comment: thats not the problem , i have checked it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Postman app (chrome webstore) to test your API calls and see if they're valid. If that doesn't help you resolve the issue paste the input and output.